# delete all except for middle edge

Tags: python

I have a mesh which looks like this.
[image]
Is there any way (script or option) to automatically delete everything except the middle edge?

Comment: Invert the selection with Ctrl i then delete with X?

Comment: I would like to have a python script that does everything automatically. So that I do not have to select the middle edge at all. The model is very big and alt+left click select for the middle edge dosnt work on this model

Comment: Can you breakdown what exactly you exactly expect the script to be capable of? If you could list the step, maybe we can help implement them in a script, but at the moment it's not clear what is the "everything" you refer to and what is a "middle edge" in this context.

Comment: In the image, the "middle edge" is the selected edge (highlighted in orange), so I want only that edge after I run the script. Everything else should be deleted

Comment: For a script to identify these edges, it would be good to know more information about them that defines their uniqueness. For example, if they were miraculously indexed by some sequential ascending order (e.g. edges 50 thru 66) or something like that, it would be easy to select them. Maybe you could identify them geometrically since they seem to be the middle edges of the "U" shape.